# Show secured images with Laravel 5 and Blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I don't want that users can access images from simply using a URL like http://laravel.dev/123.jpg. Therefore I store all images in the **storage directory**, instead of storing them in the public folder.

With a controller like this

```
public function show($id) {
    $img = storage_path('my_images/123.jpg');
    return response()->download($img, null, [], null);
}
```

the image is correctly displayed by Laravel 5, although it is stored outside from the public folder.

Great up to this point ... but I want to use Blade and surround the image with some more details. Therefore my **controller** looks like this

```
public function show($id) {
    $picture = Picture::find($id);
    $img = storage_path('my_images/123.jpg');
    return view('pictures.show', array('picture' => $picture, 'img' => $img));
}
```

and the **view** like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Picture {{ $picture->id }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Picture {{ $picture->id }}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: {{ $picture->name }}</li>
            <li>Description: {{ $picture->description }}</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="{{ $image }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

which obviously does not work, because the location of the image is not publicly accessible (which ist the intention).

What do I have to use instead of `<img src="{{ $image }}">` to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the src attribute to call the URL of your first controller, this will work for you.

In other words, let's say, you have a route called `image.show` with that code.

```
public function show($id) {
    $img = storage_path('my_images/123.jpg');
    return response()->download($img, null, [], null);
}
```

So in your blade:

```
<img src={{route("image.show",$img_object)}}">
```

Comment: That does the job! Thank you.

The only thing I don't like so much with this solution is, that the client will actually call the server twice - the first time for the whole page and the second time for retrieving the image.

Isn't there a way to simply transfer the image as kind-of binary like `<img binary="01001010101...">` instead of offering a source?

Comment: Actually that's the case with any resource you host in your page (images, css, js) the client will make another server request for each.